# How to subtract two dates and compare the result against another field?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm pretty new with MongoDB. I have a collection with the following document structure:

```
{
  "active": true,
  "days": [],
  "start_date": ISODate("..."),
  "end_date": ISODate("..."),
  "frequency": 600000,
  "latest_execution_date": ISODate("...")
} 
{
  "active": false,
  "days": [1, 2, 3],
  "start_date": ISODate("..."),
  "end_date": ISODate("..."),
  "frequency": 600000,
  "latest_execution_date": ISODate("...")
} 
{
  "active": true,
  "days": [2, 5],
  "start_date": ISODate("..."),
  "end_date": ISODate("..."),
  "frequency": 600000,
  "latest_execution_date": ISODate("...")
}
```

I want to find, the active documents with array of "days" empty or the current day of the week is in the array and the current date is between "start_date" and "end_date" and the difference between "latest_execution_date" and the current date is greater than "frequency".

I have create this query and it's works for me but the MongoDB server that I'm using do not support "$where" any more.

```
db.myCollection.find({          
    $where: function() {
        const currentDate = new Date();                
        const latestExecution = new Date(this.latest_execution_date);
        return (
            this.active &&
            this.start_date <= currentDate &&
            this.end_date >= currentDate &&
            (this.days.includes(currentDate.getDay()) || this.days.length === 0) &&
            (this.latest_execution_date === null || ((currentDate.valueOf() - latestExecution.valueOf()) >= this.frequency))
        );
    }
})
```

I'm trying to replace the "find" by "aggregation" but I'm stuck with the subtraction and the comparison, this is what I have right now but the $cmp is not working properly.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
    $project: {            
        active: "$active",        
        start_date: "$start_date",
        end_date: "$end_date",
        days: "$days",
        frequency: "$frequency"
        latest_execution_date: "$latest_execution_date",
        dateDifference: {                  
            $subtract: [ new Date(), "$latest_execution_date" ]              
        },
        compare: {
            $cmp: [ "$dateDifference", "$frequency" ]
        }
    }
},
{
    $match: {        
        active:{$eq:true},        
        start_date:{$lte: ISODate("...")},
        end_date:{$gte: ISODate("...")},              
        $and: [
            { $or:[ { days:{$size:0}}, { days:{$elemMatch:{$eq:<day of the week>} } }] },
            { $or: [ { latest_execution_date: { $eq: null } }, { compare: { $lte: 0 } } ] }
        ]       
    }     
}
])
```

The main issue that I'm having with this approach is the "$cmp" that is returning always "-1" it doesn't matter if the "frequency" is greater or not not. I have checked the data types and the frequency is Int32 and dateDifference is Int64. Converting frequency to Int64 ( frequency: { $convert: { input: "$frequency", to: "long" }}) I got the same.

Someone know how to fix this issue? or have a different approch to solve this problem?
All advise, suggestions or critics are very welcome .

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had had not time to post my solution.
I'm letting it here in case of it helps someone.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([{
    $project: {            
        ...
        dateDifference: {                  
           $subtract: [{ $subtract: [new Date(), '$latest_execution_date'] }, '$frequency']            
        }
    }
},
{
    $match: {        
       ...           
       $and: [
         { $or:[ { days:{$size:0}}, { days:{$elemMatch:{$eq:<day of the week>} } }] },
         { $or: [ { latest_execution_date: { $eq: null } }, { dateDifference:{$gte:0}} ] }
        ]       
    }     
}
])
```

Basically, I realized that I was complicating the solution for no reason, just adding a nested Subtraction was enough and then check the result.